# Content in main div overflows

Tags: html, css

I have a main div that gets overflowed the same as http://jsfiddle.net/d8kc4m2c/1/. In the fiddle, the "Words" are overflowing the content div. I noticed that when I remove the height from `#content` the problem is gone, however, in my actual html I am trying to size an image inside of `#content` as a percent which of course requires the parent height defined. Is there a way around this?

```
<body>
<div id='head'>
    Hello
</div>
<div id='content'>
    Words
    Words
    Words
    <div id='inner'>inner</div>
    <img src='http://i.imgur.com/tz2mcrM.png'>
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
     Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
     Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
     Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
     Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
     Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
     Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
     Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
    Words
</div>
```

```
html, body, #content{
height:100%;
}
#content{
  background-color:green;
}
#inner{
height:50%;
background-color:yellow;
}
img{
height:10%;    
}
```

EDIT:Added proper fiddle link. Copied code from fiddle to here.

Comment: Include your code in the question.  Links die, and then the question becomes useless to future readers with the same problem.

Comment: Your fiddle is empty and there's no code in your question. -1

Comment: Code.Goes.In.Your.Question. And what behavior are you expecting here? Your inner div is pushing the content down.

Comment: @j08691 if you look at what he's saying, you'll notice that he doesn't want a height: 100%; on #content. We wants to set it as like 500px or whatever, and the words are flowing past his content box. So, if he wants a fixed height box, it needs scroll bars if it becomes too long - like I show in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

After looking at his fiddle, you need to do this:

```
html, body, #content{
    height:75%; //Whatever your height is actually supposed to be.
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately adding a scroll bar is not an option.

Comment: Well, what do you want it to do then? You only have so many options... You can do _overflow: none;_